# I can't get the Route working in Angular please advice

Tags: angular, visual-studio, routes

I learn Angular and have a small problem. If I put the Component in my app.component.html like this it works ok,

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <app-search-books></app-search-books>
  </div>
</body>
```

but if I configure the app-routing.module.ts like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SearchBooksComponent } from './search-books/search-books.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search', component: SearchBooksComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

then nothing happens. What did I miss?

This is search-books.component.ts in the folder search-books/search-books.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-books',
  templateUrl: './search-books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-books.component.scss']
})
export class SearchBooksComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let isDone: boolean = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

replace `<app-search-books></app-search-books>` with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

[Documentation Link](https://angular.io/guide/router)

NOTE: after replacing you will get BLANK screen because you don't define root Route.

**defining root route**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/search',  pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'search', component: SearchBooksComponent }
];
```

Also, you can define wildcard route i.e. if you navigate any page which does not exist it will redirect to the defined component.

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/search',  pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Comment: I have tried that following different tutorials, the browser then show a white empty window

Comment: are you using `isDone`  flag in search-books.component.html ?

Comment: you should also consider to add a "wildcard" route for unexpected routes, otherwise you would again get a blank screen when e.g. trying to accees route 'doesNotExist': {path: '**', redirectTo: '/search' }

Comment: thanks, @RonaldKorze for the suggestion, added in answer